# Questions about InlineCell vs InlineFormula vs DisplayFormula cells

Tags: front-end, formatting, stylesheet, style, guidelines

I'm having trouble with typesetting, and can't get these questions straight in my head.

1. What is the difference between `"InlineCell"` and `"InlineFormula"` style?
2. Is one a subset of the other?
3. In what situations should I use each?
4. And why is `InlineCell` important enough to have default shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>) but `InlineFormula` is not?
5. Does `"InlineFormula"` have anything to do with an `"DisplayFormula"` cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with writting books or articles in Mathematica so let me just add technicall notes. For use cases I'd search around using those styles as keywords:

- [How do I use the styles "DisplayFormula" and "DisplayFormulaNumbered"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13831/5478)
- ["How is the cell style of a given cell resolved."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13785/5478)

---

#### 4

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> starts an *Inline cell* which is not the same thing as an `"InlineCell"`. But one step at a time.

So an *Inline cell* is special as it is a cell inside a cell (notice that you can't just create it between cells with <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>). And now an `"InlineCell"` is a style that is used for that area automatically after it is created. (more info in [Order/Dependency of Styles in a Stylesheet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14835/5478) by John Fultz)

Notice also that `"InlineCell"` style is not even explicitly present in `Cell[]` expression whereas for custom setting e.g. `DefaultNewInlineCellStyle -> {"InlineFormula"}`, the `"InlineFormula"` will be there. So the former style is really a core stuff.

#### 1; 2; 3

As you can see from definition in `Core.nb` it is not so much about styling but about behavior/experience:

```
Cell[StyleData["InlineCell"],
 ShowCodeAssist->False,
 CodeAssistOptions->{"DynamicHighlighting"->False},
 TextAlignment->Left,
 TranslationOptions->{"Enabled"->False},
 LanguageCategory->"Formula",
 ScriptLevel->1,
 StyleMenuListing->None
]
```

so is the case with `"InlineFormula"` (from `Default.nb`):

```
Cell[StyleData["InlineFormula"],
 StripStyleOnPaste->True,
 HyphenationOptions->{"HyphenationCharacter"->"\[Continuation]"},
 LanguageCategory->"Formula",
 ScriptLevel->1,
 SingleLetterItalics->True,
 MenuSortingValue->1650,
 FontSize->Inherited 1.05
]
```

but here that `SingleLetterItalics` and enlarged `FontSize` suggest it is meant for... formulas, in mathematical sense probably.

So you can compare those options and set `DefaultNewInlineCellStyle` whatever you like. You can set also other styles or modify those, whatever fit your needs.

Comment: This is great info.  This helps sooo much.

Comment: Is it possible to put `DefaultNewInlineCellStyle -> {"InlineFormula"}` in the private stylesheet somewhere so it affects all cells in the notebook?  Would it go in the "Notebook" Style data?  I know I can do this in the Mathematica preferences too, but want to know if this is possible.

Comment: I guess this is a part of a larger questions... "Can you embed any and maybe all Mathematica settings of the option inspector into a stylesheet?"  It would be great to not have to rely on and remember what options I have selected in the options inspector in case I had to reinstall Mathematica from scratch at some point.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain are you familiar with: [tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStylesheets.html)?

Comment: I took a look a while back. I'll check it out again.  Ty